# Plesk 9: how to create a subdomain pointing to a folder in main web root?

Tags: subdomain

How do I create a subdomain in Plesk **9** so that it would point to a folder inside web root of my main site?

I want both sub.domain.com and domain.com/sub point to the same folder /var/www/htdocs/domain.com/httpdocs/sub

[Plesk 9](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.3-clients-guide/) unlike previous versions does not ask me how and where I want to host a subdomain... Why, btw?

Previously I used CPanel everywhere and liked it for the level of control it gives me. Though, it can look complex to first-time user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself. 
Published a solution in my blog:
http://www.fractalizer.ru/frpost_418/plesk-9-adding-a-subdomain-tp-custom-folder-inside-webroot/

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.parallels.com/eu/download/plesk/products/

"When you download Parallels Plesk Panel from our website, you are downloading a free, fully functional version, activated for 1-domain and 1-email."

Are you using the free version?

Comment: Probably. Does it change anything if it is "fully functional version"?

Comment: Addition: no, I am not because I already added 2 domains without problem